# Django rest framework get validation error object in detail

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

> [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]

How get code from this object. I want separate error code for custom error response, i tried many solutions but i didn't get any working answer.

Comment: `the_list[0].code`?

Comment: can you show the code snippet? AFIK, this ***class representation*** will go away if you use DRF response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks it is working like a charm

Answer (score 9):

I found myself wanting to read the string field of the Error.

So for an error like:

```
<Response status_code=400, "application/json"> 
{'field_name': [ErrorDetail(string='the error message', code='invalid')]}
```

To get the string (e.g. for testing), I've used:

```
self.assertEqual(str(response.data['field_name'][0]), 'the error message')
```